# Could Maiar ever take non-humanoid form?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, maiar

Could Maiar ever take non-humanoid form?

All 3 forms that I'm aware of were human/humanoid (5 Council Wizards, Sauron, and Balrogs).

Comment: I'm don't recall Balrogs being described as humanoids. Where did you get that?

Comment: @Zottek - the one in the movie look humanoid. Aside from maybe-having-wings, I am pretty sure that the books' descriptions also were humanodidy

Comment: @Zottek - "Something was coming up behind them. What it was could not be seen: it was like a great shadow, in the middle of which was a dark form, of **man-shape** maybe, yet greater; and a power and terror seemed to be in it and to go before it."

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes.

> Now Sauron knew well, as did all in that land, the fate that was
>   decreed for the hound of Valinor, and it came into his thought that he
>   himself would accomplish it.  Therefore he took upon himself the form
>   of a werewolf...

and

> Then Sauron shifted shape, from wolf to serpent, and from monster to
>   his own accustomed form;

from "Of Beren and Luthien" in "The Silmarillion".